# Complex line integral $\int_{0}^{\pi+i} |\cos^2(t)| dt$

Tags: complex-analysis, line-integrals

I want to calculate $\int_{[0,\pi+i]}|\cos^2(t)|dt$.

Now I got
$$\int_{[0,\pi+i]}|\cos^2(t)|dt = \int_{0}^{\pi+i}\cos^2(t)dt = \frac{1}{2}(t+\sin(t)\cos(t))|_{t=0}^{t=\pi+i}=\frac{1}{2}(\pi+i+i\sinh(1)\cosh(1))$$
But this way seems too easy, did I do something wrong?
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: $|\cos^2(t)| = \cos^2(t)$ holds for *real* arguments, but here $t$ takes also complex (non-real) values.

Comment: Which path from $0$ to $\pi+i$ are you taking? I matters as $|\cos^2t|$ isn't analytic.

Comment: So $$\int_{[0,\pi+i]}|\cos^2(t)|dt = \int_{0}^{\pi+i}\sqrt{\cos^2(t)\overline{\cos^2(t)}}dt$$?

Comment: Yes, although it's perhaps more convenient to use $|\cos^2t|=(\Re\cos t)^2+(\Im\cos t)^2$. In any case, you'll want to introduce symbols for $\Re t,\,\Im t$.

Comment: @J.G. I am taking the following path $\gamma:[0,1]\to\mathbb{C}, \gamma(t)=0+(\pi+i-0)*t$

Comment: In other words, the path is $t=(\pi+i)u,\,u\in[0,\,1]$. So writing the integral as$$(\pi+i)\int_0^1\left|\cos^2[(\pi+i)u]\right|du$$may help.

Comment: @J.G. thanks for your answers, so using $\cos(x+iy)=\cos(x)\cosh(y)-i\sin(x)\sinh(y)$ 
$$(\pi+i)\int_{0}^{\pi+i}(\cos(\pi t)\cosh(t))^2+(\sin(\pi t)\sinh(t))^2dt$$

Comment: You'd want the upper limit to be $1$, but apart from that it's fine. Then you can evaluate with e.g. exponentials.